# how to include variable value in command argument in the shell script?

Tags: shell

This script statements in *certmgmt.sh*-

```
 update_keystore(){   
     keystore_file_path="/data/cert/keystore.jks"
     kestore_password="pass@word"
     temp_cert_path="/data/cert/temp_cert_file.cer"
     cert_alias="root";

     command="keytool -importcert -file $temp_cert_path -keystore $keystore_file_path -alias $cert_alias  -keypass $kestore_password -storepass $kestore_password -noprompt"
     $("$command")
 }
```

This is the output of function execution

```
pz-active-user# /usr/certmgmt.sh update_keystore
usr/certmgmt.sh: line 1381: keytool -importcert -file /data/cert/temp_cert_file.cer -keystore /data/cert/keystore.jks -alias root  -keypass pass@word -storepass pass@word -noprompt: No such file or directory
```

But if I run this directly from the terminal, it works.

```
pz-active-user# keytool -importcert -file /data/cert/temp_cert_file.cer -keystore /data/cert/keystore.jks -alias root  -keypass pass@word -storepass pass@word -noprompt
```

Comment: Not immediately related, but read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `command` variable and the `$(...)` command substitution. You can call `keytool` directly like you did at the command line:

```
update_keystore() {   
     keystore_file_path="/data/cert/keystore.jks"
     keystore_password="pass@word"
     temp_cert_path="/data/cert/temp_cert_file.cer"
     cert_alias="root"

     keytool -importcert -file "$temp_cert_path" -keystore "$keystore_file_path" -alias "$cert_alias" -keypass "$keystore_password" -storepass "$keystore_password" -noprompt
}
```